# Proof of Linear Independence for a Subset of Polynomial Set

Tags: linear-algebra

I have tried approaching this problem in the way elaborated below, but I still feel I am missing some precision in the proof. The problem is as follows.

Prove that the set
$$T = \left\{ t_0, t-t_0, (t-t_0)^2, \ldots, (t-t_0)^n \right\}\in\mathcal{P}_n,\quad n\in\mathbb{N},\quad t_0\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$$
is a lineraly independent set.

I have come to the conclusion that it is sufficient to prove that $\alpha_0=\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\ldots=\alpha_n=0$ in
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i \sum_{k=0}^i\binom{i}{k}t^{i-k}t_0^k=0.$$
I then concluded the following.
$$\binom{i}{k}\neq0,\quad t_0^k\neq 0$$
This should be enough to prove that all $\alpha_i$ must be zero if there weren't for the outermost sum. I cannot wrap my head around the consequences of dual summation in this case and why all $\alpha_i$ must be zero after $i$ goes from $0$ to $n$ Isn't there some probability that certain $t^{i-k}$ could cancel out in the outermost summation? Am I taking the wrong approach to my proof?

Comment: You're doing it too much systematically. Look at the coefficient of $t^{n}$ in your sum. What can you tell about it? Then proceed to the coefficient of $t^{n-1}$ and so on.

Comment: I see the direction you're advising me to go after, but I fail to see the connection. I obviously has got to make perfect sense, but I just see to fail it.

Comment: Do you see that the coefficient of $t^{n}$ in the sum is exactly $\alpha_{n}$?

Comment: Yes, that I saw from the beginning. That means that $\alpha_n$ will always be $0$. But I'm lost with the rest of the coefficients.

Comment: If $\alpha_{n}=0$ then you've got the same problem now only with $n-1$ instead of $n$. Can you repeat this argument also for $\alpha_{n-1}$ then?